# R select previous car ownerships within 6 months

Tags: r

Edited for clarity:

I am quite new to R. I have a data frame with vehicles with multiple ownership start and end dates. I am looking for vehicles with previous ownerships within 6 months of their current ownership.

```
vhc_key     start_date  end_date
1           2006-12-16  2015-10-05
1           2015-11-21  NA
2           2014-01-14  2014-02-14
2           2014-03-14  NA
3           2014-01-14  2014-02-14
3           2015-03-14  NA
```

Result:

```
vhc_key     start_date  end_date
1           2006-12-16  2015-10-05
2           2014-01-14  2014-02-14
```

TRUE = vehicle 1 and 2, their previous end dates are within 6 months of their last start dates. 
FALSE = vehicle 3, its previous end_date 2014-02-14 is not within 6 months of its last start date 2015-03-14.

With Dplyr it would be something like this, yet this does not seem to work:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(vhc_key) %>%
  filter(end_date >= max(start_date) - months(6))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain more? How are rows selected? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Are you comparing the last end_date for each vhc_key?

Comment: I aim to select rows for each vehicle with an end date that falls within 6 months before the max start date of each vehicle. Dplyr would be something like:
df <- df %>%
  group_by(vhc_key) %>%
  filter(end_date IS BETWEEN max(start_date) AND max(start_date)-6 months)

Comment: You have the end date of 'vhc_key' as NA.  So in that case, do we take the previous end_date Or it by comparing each element for end_date with max of start_date and then select only vhc_key that have all the comparisons TRUE

Comment: In case the end_date is NA we could delete this row, only keeping the vhc_keys with an end_date within 6 months before the maximum start date of each vehicle

Comment: Based on your logic, it is not all TRUE for vhc_key 1

Comment: For vhc_key 1 there are two rows. This vehicle was owned by a first owner between 2006-12-16 and 2015-10-05. This vehicle was owned by a second owner between 2015-11-21 and 2016-08-05. I am looking to select vehicles who had a previous owner in the half year before their last start date. For vehicle 1 this would be the case since 2015-10-05 (end_date) is within 6 months before 2015-11-21 (max start_date)

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: with your new edit, it is working for me.  Do you have columns as `Date` class

Comment: I have converted both columns using df$start_date = as.Date(df$start_date), yet it does not work. It is running for a long time without any output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work, assuming that your dataset is properly ordered (in terms of start date for each vehicle).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt = read.table(text = "vhc_key     start_date  end_date
                1           2006-12-16  2015-10-05
                1           2015-11-21  NA
                2           2014-01-14  2014-02-14
                2           2014-03-14  NA
                3           2014-01-14  2014-02-14
                3           2015-03-14  NA", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)


dt %>% 
  mutate(start_date = ymd(start_date),                                                  # update columns to date-time (if they are not)
         end_date = ymd(end_date)) %>%
  group_by(vhc_key) %>%
  mutate(dist = as.numeric(difftime(max(start_date), end_date, units="weeks"))) %>%     # get distance of end date and max start date (in weeks)
  filter(!is.na(dist) & dist <= 24) %>%                                                 # keep rows with distance up to 24 weeks (6 months)
  ungroup %>%
  select(-dist)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   vhc_key start_date   end_date
#     <int>     <date>     <date>
# 1       1 2006-12-16 2015-10-05
# 2       2 2014-01-14 2014-02-14
```